# Jetpack compose cutout shape on bottom navigation Material 3

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

How to create a cutout shape in bottom navigation with compose? It seems Material 3 doesn't support cutout shape.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bottom App Bar in Material 3 implementation for Jetpack Compose is currently under "planned" status. It is coming with some changes.

https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-app-bar/overview

[image]

Comment: It is not correct. BottomAppBar in material3 is [implemented](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#BottomAppBar(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)). Currently exists only the version with the FAB at the end of the Bar.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I am not able to find anything related to `BottomSheet` from the link that you have provided

Comment: Seems like they've decided not to implement the cutout - if their M3 solution is to put the FAB above the bar though that looks.... pretty bad.  They have the AppBar with the included FAB but they make clear that the AppBar is a screen context controller and not meant for persisting (top level) nav